# How to rotate a particular part in an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, warp

As I mentioned in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503231/animate-face-image-using-warping), I need to do a application which takes frontal face image and make it as an animated image. In this the main part is to rotate the head part. I used [this blog](http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.in/2012/11/rotation-in-3d-using-opencvs.html?showComment=1377664309249) to rotate the image.

What I did is I selected the face area, saved it as an image and passed it to the rotation code. Then I copied the rotated image to the original image. The below is the rotated image.

What I actually need is to avoid the black area and make warping. How to avoid the black area with the code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case you can use inpainting, I think it will work good.

But also take a look at thin plate spline (there are several implementations in web) and piecewise affine warp.

I mean next steps:

1) make grid uniform or face triangulation then rtansform grid nodes as you need (rotate nodes in face region).

2) apply transform (thin plate spline or piecewise affine warp).

Sorry for russian comments, it's too long for me translate them all :) if you will have troubles ask me, I'll try explain.

The wrapper for the [triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) library:

```
    //#include "triangle_wrapper.h"
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    bool myfunction (vector<size_t> i, vector<size_t> j) 
    {
      return (i[0]==j[0] && i[1]==j[1] && i[2]==j[2]);
    }

    bool myfunction2 (vector<size_t> i) 
    {
      return (i.size()==0);
    }
    //---------------------------------------------
    // триангуляция. на входе вектор точек, на выходе вектор индексов точек по треугольникам
    //--------------------------------------------- 
    vector<vector<size_t>> Triangulate(vector<Point2d>& pts)
    {
        vector<vector<size_t>> triangles;


        struct triangulateio in, out, vorout;

        in.numberofpoints = pts.size();

        in.numberofpointattributes = 0;
        in.pointlist = (REAL *) malloc(in.numberofpoints * 2 * sizeof(REAL));
        in.pointmarkerlist = (int *) malloc(in.numberofpoints * sizeof(int));

        for(int i=0;i<pts.size();i++)
        {
            in.pointlist[2*i] = pts[i].x;
            in.pointlist[2*i+1] = pts[i].y;
            in.pointmarkerlist[i]=0;
        }
        in.numberofsegments = 0;
        in.numberofholes = 0;
        in.numberofregions = 0;

        out.pointlist = (REAL *) NULL;
        out.pointattributelist = (REAL *) NULL;
        out.pointmarkerlist = (int *) NULL;
        out.trianglelist = (int *) NULL;
        out.triangleattributelist = (REAL *) NULL;
        out.neighborlist = (int *) NULL;
        out.segmentlist = (int *) NULL;
        out.segmentmarkerlist = (int *) NULL;
        out.edgelist = (int *) NULL;
        out.edgemarkerlist = (int *) NULL;
        vorout.pointlist = (REAL *) NULL;
        vorout.pointattributelist = (REAL *) NULL;
        vorout.edgelist = (int *) NULL;
        vorout.normlist = (REAL *) NULL;

        // хелп по переключателям здесь:
        // http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.switch.html

        triangulate("pczeQ", &in, &out, &vorout);

        for (int i = 0; i < out.numberoftriangles; i++) 
        {
            vector<size_t> idx(3);
            for (int j = 0; j < out.numberofcorners; j++) 
            {
                idx[j]=out.trianglelist[i * out.numberofcorners + j];
            }
            triangles.push_back(idx);
        }

        free(in.pointlist);
        free(in.pointmarkerlist);

        free(out.pointlist);
        free(out.pointattributelist);
        free(out.trianglelist);
        free(out.triangleattributelist);

        cout << "triangles.size()" <<triangles.size() << endl;

        return triangles;
    }
```

My implementation of piecewise affine warper:

```
#include "warpaffine.h"
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Вычисление габаритного прямоугольника для точек типа Point2d
// --------------------------------------------------------------
cv::Rect_<double> boundingRect(vector<Point2d>& pts)
{
    cv::Rect_<double> r;
    double minx=FLT_MAX,maxx=FLT_MIN,miny=FLT_MAX,maxy=FLT_MIN;

    for(int i=0;i<pts.size();i++)
    {
        double px=pts[i].x;
        double py=pts[i].y;
        if(minx>px){minx=px;}
        if(miny>py){miny=py;}
        if(maxx<px){maxx=px;}
        if(maxy<py){maxy=py;}
    }

    r.x=minx;
    r.y=miny;
    r.width=maxx-minx;
    r.height=maxy-miny;

    return r;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Создаем разметку точек, по принадлежности к треугольникам
// --------------------------------------------------------------
void DrawLabelsMask(Mat& imgLabel,vector<Point2d>& points,vector<vector<size_t>>& triangles)
{
    for(int i=0;i<triangles.size();i++)
    {
        Point t[3];
        int ind1=triangles[i][0];
        int ind2=triangles[i][1];
        int ind3=triangles[i][2];
        t[0].x=cvRound(points[ind1].x);
        t[0].y=cvRound(points[ind1].y);
        t[1].x=cvRound(points[ind2].x);
        t[1].y=cvRound(points[ind2].y);
        t[2].x=cvRound(points[ind3].x);
        t[2].y=cvRound(points[ind3].y);
        cv::fillConvexPoly(imgLabel, t, 3, cv::Scalar_<int>((i+1)));
    }
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Предварительный расчет коэффициентов преобразования для пар треугольников
// --------------------------------------------------------------
void CalcCoeffs(vector<Point2d>& s_0,vector<Point2d>& s_1, vector<vector<size_t>>& triangles, Mat& Coeffs)
{
    Rect_<double> Bound_0;
    Rect_<double> Bound_1;
    // Вычислили габариты
    Bound_0=boundingRect(s_0);
    Bound_1=boundingRect(s_1);
    // Предварительный расчет коэффициентов преобразования для пар треугольников
    Coeffs=Mat(triangles.size(),6,CV_64FC1);
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for
#endif
    for(int i=0;i<triangles.size();i++)
    {
        int ind1=triangles[i][0];
        int ind2=triangles[i][1];
        int ind3=triangles[i][2];
        // Исходные точки (откуда берем)
        Point2d t_0[3];
        t_0[0]=s_0[ind1]-Bound_0.tl(); // i
        t_0[1]=s_0[ind2]-Bound_0.tl(); // j
        t_0[2]=s_0[ind3]-Bound_0.tl(); // k
        // Целевые точки (куда кладем)
        Point2d t_1[3];
        t_1[0]=s_1[ind1]-Bound_1.tl(); // i
        t_1[1]=s_1[ind2]-Bound_1.tl(); // j
        t_1[2]=s_1[ind3]-Bound_1.tl(); // k

        double denom=(t_1[0].x * t_1[1].y + t_1[2].y * t_1[1].x - t_1[0].x * t_1[2].y - t_1[2].x * t_1[1].y - t_1[0].y * t_1[1].x + t_1[0].y * t_1[2].x);

        Coeffs.at<double>(i,0)= -(-t_1[2].y * t_0[1].x + t_1[2].y * t_0[0].x + t_1[1].y * t_0[2].x - t_1[1].y * t_0[0].x - t_1[0].y * t_0[2].x + t_1[0].y * t_0[1].x) / denom;
        Coeffs.at<double>(i,1)= -(t_1[2].x * t_0[1].x - t_1[2].x * t_0[0].x - t_1[1].x * t_0[2].x + t_1[1].x * t_0[0].x + t_1[0].x * t_0[2].x - t_1[0].x * t_0[1].x) / denom;
        Coeffs.at<double>(i,2)= -(t_1[2].x * t_1[1].y * t_0[0].x - t_1[2].x * t_1[0].y * t_0[1].x - t_1[1].x * t_1[2].y * t_0[0].x + t_1[1].x * t_1[0].y * t_0[2].x + t_1[0].x * t_1[2].y * t_0[1].x - t_1[0].x * t_1[1].y * t_0[2].x)/denom;
        Coeffs.at<double>(i,3)= -(t_1[1].y * t_0[2].y - t_1[0].y * t_0[2].y - t_1[2].y * t_0[1].y + t_1[2].y * t_0[0].y - t_0[0].y * t_1[1].y + t_0[1].y * t_1[0].y) / denom;
        Coeffs.at<double>(i,4)= -(-t_1[2].x * t_0[0].y + t_1[0].x * t_0[2].y + t_1[2].x * t_0[1].y - t_0[1].y * t_1[0].x - t_1[1].x * t_0[2].y + t_0[0].y * t_1[1].x) / denom;
        Coeffs.at<double>(i,5)= -(t_0[0].y * t_1[1].y * t_1[2].x - t_0[2].y * t_1[0].x * t_1[1].y - t_0[1].y * t_1[0].y * t_1[2].x + t_0[1].y * t_1[0].x * t_1[2].y + t_0[2].y * t_1[0].y * t_1[1].x - t_0[0].y * t_1[1].x * t_1[2].y) / denom;
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// Переносит изображение из img с сеткой на точках s_0
// в изображение dst с сеткой на точках s_1
// Сетка задается треугольниками.
// triangles - вектор треугольников.
// Каждый треугольник - 3 индекса вершин.
// --------------------------------------------------------------
void WarpAffine(Mat& img,vector<Point2d>& s_0,vector<Point2d>& s_1, vector<vector<size_t>>& triangles, Mat& dstLabelsMask,Mat& dst)
{
    Rect_<double> Bound_0;
    Rect_<double> Bound_1;

    // ROI (все точки должны лежать в пределах своих изображений)
    // Вычислили габариты
    Bound_0=boundingRect(s_0);
    Bound_1=boundingRect(s_1);  

    Bound_1.width=cvRound(Bound_1.width);
    Bound_1.height=cvRound(Bound_1.height);

    Bound_0.width=cvRound(Bound_0.width);
    Bound_0.height=cvRound(Bound_0.height);

    if(Bound_0.br().x>img.cols-1){Bound_0.width=(double)img.cols-1-Bound_0.x;}
    if(Bound_0.br().y>img.rows-1){Bound_0.height=(double)img.rows-1-Bound_0.y;}


    Mat I_0=img(Bound_0);

    // Переводим координаты точек в систему координат ROI
    for(int i=0;i<s_1.size();i++)
    {
    s_1[i]-=Bound_1.tl();
    }

    // Корректируем границы
    if(Bound_1.x<0)
    {
        Bound_1.x=0;
    }

    if(Bound_1.y<0)
    {
        Bound_1.y=0;
    }

    if(Bound_1.br().x>dst.cols-1)
    {
        Bound_1.width=(double)dst.cols-1-Bound_1.x;
    }

    if(Bound_1.br().y>dst.rows-1)
    {
        Bound_1.height=(double)dst.rows-1-Bound_1.y;
    }


    // Назначаем ROI
    Mat I_1=dst(Bound_1);

    // Предварительный расчет коэффициентов преобразования для пар треугольников
    Mat Coeffs;
    CalcCoeffs(s_0,s_1,triangles,Coeffs);

    // Сканируем изображение и переносим с него точки на шаблон
    #ifdef _OPENMP
    #pragma omp parallel for
    #endif
    for(int i=0;i<I_1.rows;i++)
    {
        Point2d W(0,0);
        for(int j=0;j<I_1.cols;j++)
        {
            double x=j;
            double y=i;
            int Label=dstLabelsMask.at<int>(i,j)-1;
            if(Label!=(-1))
            {               
                W.x=Coeffs.at<double>(Label,0)*x+Coeffs.at<double>(Label,1)*y+Coeffs.at<double>(Label,2);
                W.y=Coeffs.at<double>(Label,3)*x+Coeffs.at<double>(Label,4)*y+Coeffs.at<double>(Label,5);
                if(cvRound(W.x)>0 && cvRound(W.x)<I_0.cols && cvRound(W.y)>0 && cvRound(W.y)<I_0.rows)
                {
                    I_1.at<Vec3b>(i,j)=I_0.at<Vec3b>(cvRound(W.y),cvRound(W.x));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cv::GaussianBlur(I_1,I_1,Size(3,3),0.5);    
}
```

I have also TPS, but it slower than  piecewise affine warper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain what is "Inpainting"? I think links are missing?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html  and in opencv's samples you can find inpaint.cpp example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will work on it and let you konow the results. I will wait for a day to accept this as answer as other experts can have a look and post their views.

Comment: As you said before trying this kinda rotation I tried with Thin plate spline ( http://ipwithopencv.blogspot.ro/2010/01/thin-plate-spline-example.html ) and piecewise affine warp (http://code.google.com/p/imgwarp-opencv/), but am facing performance issue when I port to devices like IPAD. So I took this approach. Do you know any implementations of thin plate spline or piecewise affine warp which is good in performance? Sorry for troubling more!

Comment: I have added some code to answer. There russian comments, but I too lazy to translate them :) In a few word it works as follows: 1) you assign one set of points for each image. 2) Triangulate one of sets, so you get a set of edges for point sets. 3) Apply WarpAffine with parameters s0 and s1 as point sets for source image and destimnation image respectively. triangles - indexes of points in every triangle.  I have wrote it long time ago and it works correct and very fast, but may be it need some additinal boundary checks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and the reply, I will work on it and let you know my results. I have only one doubt right now. Do I need to use triangle library?

Comment: Not mandatory, you only need define triangles. As vector of vectors of points indexes. You can do it in any way you want.

Comment: As I rememberm you need define some constants in triangle.h, they defined in my version as follows : #define TRILIBRARY
#define NO_TIMER

Comment: Hi Can you please guide me how to compile your code? I am using Mingw in windows. I downloaded triangle library and included in my project. still am facing problems. I spent around 5 hours on this, and still am not success.

Comment: I have compiled it in vs2010. What part of code produces error messages?

Comment: The problem is with Triangle library.Can you please let me know the files from triangle library to be included into the project to compile your code? There are multiple "Mains" in the triangle library. I could see main in ( showme.c, tricall.c and triangle.c)

Comment: I only use triangle.cpp and triangle.h in both (in the beginning) I have defined #define TRILIBRARY #define NO_TIMER the first define turn off all main functions, the second turns off time.h header.

Comment: I tried it but its not working. I couldnt see any ifdef's around main functions in showme.c and tricall.c. or am I doing it correctly? I defined the two constants in triangle.h, is that correct?

Comment: You are not need use showme.c and tricall.c. You only need triangle.c and triangle.h. I have defined these defines in both. You can also do it in compiler options. Anyway, you need triangulate points only once. MAy be it'll be easyer to do it with triangle executable file. Or other traingulator. QHull for example. Or I can send you my project files to e-mail.

Comment: I am getting the error **undefined reference to `triangulate(char*, triangulateio*, triangulateio*, triangulateio*)'** after doing the abvoce

Comment: can you send me your project to my mail? i9processor@gmail.com

Comment: Define also ANSI_DECLARATORS.

Comment: Ok, I have sent you the archive.

Comment: Yes I have declared that too! but same response